# Client not receiving all messages using websockets

Tags: php, javascript, html, websocket

I have a WebSockets server set up on localhost, using [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/). The client is sending 2 messages to the server ('hi server') at almost the exact same time as so

```
socket.send('hi server');
socket.send('hi server');
```

The server is receiving both messages and replying back with the message 'sup client'.

```
...
case "hi server": $this->send($user->socket,"sup client"); break;
...
function send($client,$msg){ 
    echo "> ".$msg;
    $msg = $this->wrap($msg);
    socket_write($client,$msg,strlen($msg));
    echo "! ".strlen($msg)."\n";
} 
...
function wrap($msg=""){ return chr(0).$msg.chr(255); }
```

The php log looks like this:
[image: phplog]

The code for the client receiving messages:

```
socket.onmessage = function(msg)
{
    log("Received: " + msg.data);
}
```

What the client is actually logging inside the div element:
[image: client]

I have no idea why the client is only processing one message when the websocket server sent 2. I should have 2 'Received: sup client' in that div tag. I'm thinking maybe its sending the messages a bit too fast for the JavaScript or something.

Comment: Send a unique identifier with each message. Even a simple global incrementing value will do. This will let you see which message is failing. If it's the same one consistently, then maybe your code is buggy. If it's random, then there's a system bug and/or race condition somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I used this to eventually find the problem (solution below). phpwebsocket...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more testing, I found that actually, only the first response was not being sent by the websockets server. I did some googling and it turns out that there is an issue with [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) - the handshake wasn't being done properly or something. On [this page](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/updates/list) I found a solution that goes as follows:

Change line 102 in websocket.class.php

```
From: socket_write($user->socket,$upgrade.chr(0),strlen($upgrade.chr(0)));
To:   socket_write($user->socket,$upgrade.chr(0).chr(255),strlen($upgrade)+2);
```

(added a non-breaking space)

Works fine now. :)